# can we use Expression Blend for Asp.net MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expression-blend

I am New to MVC, and i am familiar with WPF Can I use Blend to design richer UI for Asp.net MVC web applications, if so , How can I integrate to my MVC Project??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No . At least not yet. Anybody who knows power of WPF and Blend wishes for this capability in Microsoft Visual Studio. Blend would be a really great tool for web applications that need to have lot's of javascripts and css codes for their controls behavior and beauty. You can't compare a Silverlight application with a regular asp.net web application. So as Silverlight stands behind for many years now I think Microsoft should replace it with (asp.net+Blend).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the latest blend for visual studio 2013 now comes with html/css support. Unfortunately, it is still geared towards windows apps.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1982184.aspx?Blend+for+Visual+Studio+HTML+CSS+WYSIWYG+editor+only+for+windows+apps+not+for+web+asp+net+apps+

Accordingly, it doesn't seem like it will work with MVC.